# Can't download packages in Atom Text Editor

Tags: linux, npm, package, atom-editor, apm

I've been trying to download packages using the GUI provided by Atom but I'm running into the same errors:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   '/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   '--globalconfig',
1 verbose cli   '/home/trv/.atom/.apm/.apmrc',
1 verbose cli   '--userconfig',
1 verbose cli   '/home/trv/.atom/.apmrc',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'https://www.atom.io/api/packages/atom-discord/versions/2.0.2/tarball',
1 verbose cli   '--target=9.4.4',
1 verbose cli   '--disturl=https://atom.io/download/electron',
1 verbose cli   '--arch=x64',
1 verbose cli   '--global-style'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.13
3 info using node@v12.14.1
4 verbose npm-session f9daf1edbdd22347
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
7 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for https://www.atom.io/api/packages/atom-discord/versions/2.0.2/tarball request to https://www.atom.io/api/packages/atom-discord/versions/2.0.2/tarball failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN www.atom.io
8 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 2ms
9 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 20063ms
10 verbose type system
11 verbose stack FetchError: request to https://www.atom.io/api/packages/atom-discord/versions/2.0.2/tarball failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN www.atom.io
11 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-fetch-npm/src/index.js:68:14)
11 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:223:5)
11 verbose stack     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:406:9)
11 verbose stack     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:223:5)
11 verbose stack     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
11 verbose stack     at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
11 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21)
12 verbose cwd /tmp/apm-install-dir-2022210-70305-1gp2mr9.ertgl
13 verbose Linux 5.13.0-35-generic
14 verbose argv "/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/bin/node" "/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js" "--globalconfig" "/home/trv/.atom/.apm/.apmrc" "--userconfig" "/home/trv/.atom/.apmrc" "install" "https://www.atom.io/api/packages/atom-discord/versions/2.0.2/tarball" "--target=9.4.4" "--disturl=https://atom.io/download/electron" "--arch=x64" "--global-style"
15 verbose node v12.14.1
16 verbose npm  v6.14.13
17 error code EAI_AGAIN
18 error errno EAI_AGAIN
19 error request to https://www.atom.io/api/packages/atom-discord/versions/2.0.2/tarball failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN www.atom.io
20 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I also tried using `apm` to download the packages manually instead of the GUI. Here's the error log:

```
trv@lexy:~$ apm install atom-discord
Installing atom-discord to /home/trv/.atom/packages ✗

npm ERR! code EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! errno EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! request to https://www.atom.io/api/packages/atom-discord/versions/2.0.2/tarball failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN www.atom.io

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/trv/.atom/.apm/_logs/2022-03-10T14_30_47_677Z-debug.log
```

Note:

- I'm using Lubuntu 21.10 x86_64. Didn't encounter these errors when I used Windows 10.
- My internet connection is decent and isn't likely the issue.

Comment: Do you have shell commands installed `Atom>Instal Shell Commands`?

Comment: @VarunW. Yes, I have them enabled.

Comment: I would recommend you put this question in [atom discussions](https://github.com/atom/atom/discussions) because over there there are a lot more people who might help.